# Changing colorIndex of grommet components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, grommet

How do i change the colorIndex of the the components in grommet like icons ,graphs,?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `colorIndex` property, much the same as you would on other Grommet components.

```
<Line values={...} max={...} colorIndex='ok' />
```

The available colors can be found at https://grommet.github.io/docs/color/.